# react native can not find view by nativeID from native IOS

Tags: react-native, findviewbyid

I tried but no luck to me, here is my code:

```
if let nativeID = nativeID{
        if let controller = RCTPresentedViewController(){
          if let imageView = self.searchForView(view: controller.view, nativeId: nativeID){
//            imageView.hero.id = nativeID
          }
        }
      }
```

here is searchview method

```
func searchForView(view: UIView, nativeId: String) -> UIView? {
    if (view.nativeID == nativeId) {
      return view
    }else{
      for subView in view.subviews {
        if let v = searchForView(view: subView, nativeId: nativeId) {
          return v
        }
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

can someone help